# How do I update the canvas all at once? And efficiency in sandpiles

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm currently writing code using javascript with the p5.js library for "sandpiles". A sandpile is a mathematic structure in a discrete 2d space where "sand", an integer is placed at a point, and will "topple" onto adjacent cells. I'm relatively new to coding so I don't know the most efficient way to do this.

Currently I'm using a 2D array I made from creating a global sandpiles array and within my setup function making each element within that array its own array, allowing my to have an x and y index which covers the canvas.

My problem comes when I go to show the value (the "amount of sand") of each pixel - every single pixel is looked at individually and replaced with a "point" of a certain colour depending it's value

```
function update() {

for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        if (sandpiles[x][y] == int(0)) {
            stroke(255, 255, 0);
        } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 1) {
            stroke(0, 185, 63);
        } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 2) {
            stroke(0, 104, 255);
        } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 3) {
            stroke(122, 0, 229);
        } else {
            stroke(255, 0, 0);
        }
        point(x, y);
    }
}
```

Sandpiles as a construct have this very nice symmetry to them and I was wondering if it would be possible to stop the screen while the pixels are drawn so that each "state" of the call can be seen at once and not the individual pixels. Also, I know there is probably a way to do this with javascript itself which would work more nicely so if anyone could guide me on a function that js has for dealing with each pixel in a more elegant way I would very much appreciate it. Also, due to the the fact that I'm checking through every single pixel twice for each draw of the canvas (once to topple, once to update), is there a way to make the searching more efficient or would I have to include a specific search algorithm? Thank you.

**EDIT:**
Below is the whole code - I've removed a few of the optional parameters so it's a bit easier to read, I hope I'm doing it right.

```
total_sand = 10000;
sandpiles = [];
var next_sandpiles;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(301, 301);
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        sandpiles[x] = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            sandpiles[x][y] = 0;
        }
    }
    next_sandpiles = sandpiles;

    //STARTING CONDITIONS
    if (width % 2 == 0) {
        sandpiles[width/2][height/2] = total_sand;
    } else {
        sandpiles[(width-1)/2][(height-1)/2] = total_sand;
    }


}

function topple() {

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            if (sandpiles[x][y] > 3) {

                next_sandpiles[x][y] = next_sandpiles[x][y] - 4;
                if (x > 0) {
                    next_sandpiles[x-1][y]++;
                }
                if (x < width - 1) {
                    next_sandpiles[x+1][y]++;
                }
                if (y > 0) {
                    next_sandpiles[x][y-1]++;
                }
                if (y < height - 1) {
                    next_sandpiles[x][y+1]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    sandpiles = next_sandpiles;
}

function update() {

    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            if (sandpiles[x][y] == int(0)) {
                stroke(255, 255, 0); // colour 0
            } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 1) {
                stroke(0, 185, 63); // colour 1
            } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 2) {
                stroke(0, 104, 255); // colour 2
            } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 3) {
                stroke(122, 0, 229); // colour 3
            } else {
                stroke(255, 0, 0); // colour 4
            }
            point(x, y);
        }
    }

}

function draw() {

    // while (toppling) {
    //  topple();
    // }

    topple();

    update();

    // noLoop();    

}
```

Comment: Can you please post a simple [mcve]? Can you be more specific about what you mean by drawing each state instead of individual pixels?

Comment: By drawing each state I mean drawing every pixel (or showing the new pixels) all at once. The draw function consists of a topple function and an update function, and the update function goes through every pixel in the 2D array and updates them one at a time. Instead I was hoping there was a function that would "freeze" the canvas when the pixels began being plotted and "unfreeze" when they're done so they are all drawn at once. Thank you! And I will get to posting the proper code soon, apologies.

Comment: I was pretty sure that P5.js was already double-buffered. I'll investigate further if you post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `loadPixels()` and `updatePixels()` with the `pixels` array:

```
function update() {

loadPixels();
var r;
var g;
var b;

for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        if (sandpiles[x][y] == int(0)) {
            r = 255;
            g = 255;
            b = 0;
        } else if(sandpiles[x][y] == 1) {
            r = 0;
            g = 185;
            b = 63;
        } // add as many colors as you please
        var index = (x + y * width)*4;
        pixels[index] = r;
        pixels[index+1] = g;
        pixels[index+2] = b;
        pixels[index+3] = 255; // alpha
    }
}

updatePixels();
}
```